# Create IPv6 subnet, using tunnel and dynamic public IPv4 address?

Tags: networking, ipv6

I am wanting to create an IPv6 subnet, using a 6to4 tunnel, while being within a NATed IPv4 network, that has a dynamic public address. Can anyone suggest how I can go about this? I looked at Hurricane Electric, but they appear to require a static public IPv4 address.

I am looking to use a Pi using Raspberry Stretch.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wanting to create an IPv6 subnet, using a 6to4 tunnel, while being within a NATed IPv4 network, that has a dynamic public address

6to4 behind NAT actually works mostly the same as HE.net Tunnelbroker behind NAT.

In both cases you need to configure an IP6-in-IP4 interface (the type is `sit` in Linux); the only difference is that 6to4 tunnels should have `any` as the remote endpoint and use `::192.88.99.1` as the route gateway, while HE.net tunnels have a specific endpoint address.

<sup>*(Technically 6to4 can directly use `remote 192.88.99.1` as the endpoint, but using `remote any` tells Linux to detect and enable direct traffic between two 6to4-using hosts, bypassing the relay.)*</sup>

And in both cases you need to make sure your IPv4 router is capable of NATing "protocol 41" outbound (that's IPv6-in-IP), and if possible also configure a static **inbound** NAT ("port forward") rule for it as well. If inbound NAT for proto41 is not configured, you'll periodically lose the ability to receive incoming IPv6 connections.

Note that most ISPs do not run 6to4 relays anymore – in fact, your closest 6to4 gateway might be owned by Hurricane Electric. Additionally, note that anycast 6to4 is [officially deprecated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7526) as of 2015, and some ISPs no longer forward IPv4 packets to this address at all.

> I looked at Hurricane Electric, but they appear to require a static public IPv4 address.

They support updating the tunnel endpoint [through an HTTP API call](https://forums.he.net/index.php?topic=1994.0), in a similar manner to "dynamic DNS" services. You can most likely schedule `ddclient` or even `curl` to make the updates.

So using HE.net or a similar service only has advantages – you would get a *static* IPv6 prefix and wouldn't need to reconfigure the local Linux system at all, whereas 6to4 address prefixes are calculated from your IPv4 address and would therefore change very often, requiring network renumbering *and* reconfiguration of the local tunnel every time it happens.